# PermissionSDDL from Get-Printer returns nothing

Tags: powershell, printing, permissions

I'm trying to get printer permissions off of specific printers from my server. I'm currently using

```
(Get-Printer 'TEMP' -Full).PermissionSDDL | Out-File 'C:\OregonOperation.txt'
```

but it returns nothing into my text file.

Eventually I'll need to get permissions from all my printers on this server, but for now one will do.

Comment: Do you get anything returned if you don't pipe it to Out-File? ...run just `(Get-Printer 'TEMP' -Full).PermissionSDDL`

Comment: James, nothing happens when I run just that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-Printer 'TEMP' -Full | Select PermissionSDDL -ExpandProperty PermissionSDDL | Out-File 'C:\OregonOperation.txt'
```